# Is there a good way to optimise a nested for loop that is multiplying the iterations?

Tags: c#, algorithm, optimization, nested

I have a for loop that is creates a sum by multiplying the values in the loop:

```
int i;
int j;

float total = 0;
int x = 1000;

for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < x; j++)
    {
        total += i * j;
    }
}
```

Is there a *better way* of writing this? When `x` gets *larger*, the time it takes to process is *incredibly long*.

My research suggests that nested for loops are good enough, but I'm wondering if there's a way to *simplify* this.

Comment: You do the same multiplication over and over. Either this is an excercise or you oversimplified your actual problem.

Comment: You have `O(x^2)` *time complexity*, which means that if you increase `x` `10` times, the computation will last `100` times longer

Comment: _["Performance questions are on topic if they include a specific area of focus for improvement, can be answered with facts/citations (like specific timings/memory analysis), and such an answer would not be an unreasonable length (e.g. you could write an entire book on the topic)."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412875/what-makes-a-good-performance-question-on-so#comment878044_412875)_, Henry Ecker.

Comment: [This page](https://mindyourdecisions.com/blog/2015/10/25/sum-of-a-multiplication-table-sunday-puzzle/) goes into details about how Dmitry's answer works from a mathematical perspective.

Comment: For x = 1000, the sum has 36 significant bits. Given that a float stores 23+1 of them, you result will suffer from accumulation of truncation errors. Not counting that adding to a float is slower than to an int.

Answer (score 8):

You don't want nested loops at all, the *closed formula* for given `x` is

```
total = x * x * (x - 1) * (x - 1) / 4;
```

Just be careful with *integer overflow* (note `long` for both the result and for `x`)

```
long x = 1000;
long total = x * x * (x - 1) * (x - 1) / 4;
```

**Edit:** let's have a look at general case, where we have to work with arbitrary numbers, say, arrays `a` and `b`:

```
long total = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; ++i)
  for (int j = 0; j < b.Length; ++j)
    total += a[i] * b[j];
```

We can't propose closed formula in this case, but we can *optimize* the computation. We are looking for the `total` of

```
  a[0] * b[0] + a[0] * b[1] + ... + a[0] * b[m] +
  a[1] * b[0] + a[1] * b[1] + ... + a[1] * b[m] +
  ...
  a[n] * b[0] + a[n] * b[1] + ... + a[n] * b[m] = 


= a[0] * (b[0] + b[1] + ... + b[m]) +
  a[1] * (b[0] + b[1] + ... + b[m]) +
  ...
  a[n] * (b[0] + b[1] + ... + b[m]) =


= (a[0] + a[1] + ... a[n]) * (b[0] + b[1] + ... + b[m])
```

So far so good, instead of *nested loops* and `O(n * m)` complexity we have two *separated* loops and just `O(n + m)` time complexity.

Often we do such tasks with a help of *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;

...

long total = a.Sum(item => (long) item) * b.Sum(item => (long) item)
```

But you can well use good old loops:

```
long sumA = 0;

foreach (var item in a)
  sumA += item;

long sumB = 0;

foreach (var item in b)
  sumB += item;

long total = sumA * sumB;
```

Comment: To avoid overflow, another option is to divide x or x-1 (whichever is even) by 2.

Comment: @Yves Daoust: you are quite right we can put it as
`long total = x % 2 == 0 ? x / 2 * x / 2 * (x - 1) * (x - 1) : (x - 1) * (x - 1) / 4 * x * x;`.

Comment: `(x - 1) / 2 * (x - 1) / 2` :-)

Comment: @Yves Daoust: technically, `(x - 1) * (x - 1) / 4` will do: if `x * x` doesn't lead to integer overflow then we can allow ourselves `(x - 1) * (x - 1) / 4` instead of `(x - 1) / 2 * (x - 1) / 2`

Comment: Ooops, you are right. Then what about `x * x / 4` ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust: it can be proved that `x * x / 4` will do as well. The proof will be longer, though: the idea is that `(x - 1) * (x - 1)` is huge (`77937`) when `total` is over `long.MaxValue` that's why it doesn't matter if we have  `x * x / 4` or `x / 2 * x / 2`: it's `(x - 1) * (x - 1)` which is the culprit

Comment: Quite right. On second thoughts, I would rely on the maximum value of x that makes the sum exactly representable with a float, to get the same effect as the initial program (order of 2^23). Finding this exact value does not seem immediate, but it is far from causing an overflow.

Comment: This is great, thank you. Forgive my naivety, but if I was to replace i and j with arrays, such as arrayOne[i] and arrayTwo[j], I'm assuming this solution doesn't work as it's not purely mathematical anymore? 

And to other, yes this isn't a project, it's an exercise that I'm learning and trying to understand more :)

Comment: @Karma: in general case (say, if we have arbitrary arrays `a` and `b`) there's no closed formula and `O(1)` solution, but we can get rid of *nested* loops and `O(m * n)` time complexity and have two consequent loop with just `O(n + m)` time complexity. Please, see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

For your specific case, there is of course a constant-time expression (see Dmitry's answer). For a more general case, you can use

```
Σi Σj Xi.Yj = (Σi Xi).(Σj Yi)
```

This turns O(N²) to O(N).